# How I can know if a click event is counterfeit?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How I can know if a click event was generated by the user? (They used the mouse).

The opposite would be a click event triggered by a piece of JavaScript.

Think in a JavaScript library that displays advertisements. You wont want that anyone who uses the library fool you.

You need to make sure that the event is not forged.

Comment: Why you need this? To stop robot? If so, maybe you can remember the last date of that event, if less than 1 second or so, you can ignore it or mark it as robot.

Comment: @flybird ..huh? How does that help tell whether any given click was user-generated or not? I certainly can click more than once per second, and I can definitely write a bot which clicks slower than any arbitrary interval.

Comment: you can make it harder to spoof using mousedown and mouseup in addition to click()

Comment: @bummi It's not a duplicate. I want to know something different. Need to know if it is a forgery or not.

Answer (score 2):

Client code can never be trusted by the server.  Anyone can open up their browser console and totally change the code.

You might be able to do different things to confuse robots or automated scripts, but you're helpless if you are trying to prevent a forgery that targets your site specifically.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, *ANY* attempt to making this tamper-proof will fail unless you follow these pretty simple advises:

- don't do anything client-side, this problem family is a cognate of security, so you want to do everything server-side without relying on anything on the client;
- don't trust the input you receive, doubt about its origin (e.g. user-agent, cookies, HTTP request, ecc. may all be forged into a key that perfectly fits your keyhole);
- you do not really want to detect a mouse click, what you want is discriminate between human and machine, so use common techniques for that problem;
- a CAPTCHA or other task that is currently next-to-impossible to solve for machines allows you to distinguish a real human from a machine.

That said, the easiest for your use case (advertisement) is a floating button embedded in an image that randomly changes position. On click you send the coordinates and a code that you use server-side to reconstruct the position of the button and thus if the coordinates are inside the buttons boundaries.

A machine will send wrong (random) coordinates with the code and server-side you will discriminate it because the click was not inside the boundaries.

This solution obviously can be enhanced:

- smaller button on larger image (lower probability to have a lucky "false positive");
- move the button over time (this requires an SWF plugin or HTML5 canvas);
- avoid contrast that may be exploited to find the button in the image (e.g. a red button over a blue sky).

All you have to do is go to any website that has advertisements and look what they do: SWF plugins with micro-games that entice you to click it.

BTW: I don't like advertisements on web pages so maybe it's better you don't even implement that stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string 'Mouse' is found within the string representation of `e.toString()`:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.toString().indexOf('Mouse') !== -1)
});
```

If the event was generated by code then `e.toString()` returns `[object Event]`, but if it was a real mouse event it would return `[object MouseEvent]`. All I am doing is checking whether 'Mouse' is in that string to determine if it was indeed a real mouse click.

Comment: toString can be easily replaced by a function that returns any expected string. no good.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var w=[]["filter"]["constructor"]("return this")();//returns window, thanks to JSFuck
    console.log(e instanceOf MouseEvent && e.view==w && e.srcElement && e.srcElement.ownerDocument.parentWindow==w && e.target && e.target.ownerDocument.parentWindow==w);
});
```

It checks if it is an instance of the `MouseEvent` object, then checks if the `window` is the same, the `e.srcElement` exists and if it is in the same `window` and if `e.target` exists and is in the same `window`.

Comment: What about **HTTP request forging**? You could send 100 requests per second without even using a browser. On Linux just edit a text file with *vi* and send it with *wget* in a loop... No Javascript can handle that kind of attack.

Comment: @pid that is **outside** the scope of this question.

Comment: This doesn't mean that it is outside the intentions of the OP. In fact, the impression is he's concerned with a minor problem without realizing the true context he's trying to operate in.

Comment: @pid Still outside the scope. What you are suggesting is correct, and too immense to even start talking about it. But the OP only asked one thing and I'm showing my solution.